# How to access the global variable $current_user, in a .tpl file in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

How can I access the `$current_user` global variable inside a .tpl file? I need to customize certain parts of my view with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
{php}

 global $current_user;
    $this->_tpl_vars['current_user_email'] = $current_user->email1;

{/php}
```

Now use `$current_user_email` variable in tpl file for your current user.

Comment: where to define $this->_tpl_vars['current_user_email'] = $current_user->email1;

Comment: in your `.tpl` file

Comment: not working.used the variable in condition like this {if $current_user_id != 1}{/if}

Answer (score 0):

```
{$CURRENT_USER_ID}
```

this is even used in core theme tpl files. use it and for further help read that theme tpl code because it is pretty simple.